# Symmetry argument and WLOG

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a continuous derivative and that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0$. Prove that for every $\alpha \in (0,1)$, 
$$\left|\int_0^{\alpha}f(x)dx\right| \leq \frac{1}{8}\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|f'(x)|.$$

The solution goes like this: Let $g(x)=\int_0^x f(y)dy$, then $g(0)=g(1)=0$, so the maximum value of $|g(x)|$ must occur at a critical point $y\in (0,1)$ satisfying $g'(y)=f(y)=0$. We may take $\alpha = y$ hereafter.

Since $\int_0^{\alpha}f(x)dx= - \int_0^{1-\alpha}f(1-x)dx$, we may without loss of generality assume that $\alpha \leq 1/2$.

I don't understnd why the WLOG argument works in this case. Could someone please explains? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you can prove the statement for $0\leq\alpha\leq 1/2$ for *all* functions, and let us conclude that it follows for the rest of $\alpha$.

Let $\phi$ be a given function with continuous derivative on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1\phi(x)\,dx=0$, and let $\alpha>1/2$. We need to show that
$$\left|\int_0^{\alpha}\phi(x)dx\right| \leq \frac{1}{8}\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|\phi'(x)|.$$

Let $\psi(x)=-\phi(1-x)$ (thus $\psi$ also has a continuous derivative on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1\psi(x)\,dx=0$). 
Since $1-\alpha\leq1/2$, we know that
$$\left|\int_0^{1-\alpha}\psi(x)dx\right| \leq \frac{1}{8}\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|\psi'(x)|.$$
But since $\psi'(x)=\phi'(1-x)$,
$$
\frac{1}{8}\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|\phi'(x)|
=\frac{1}{8}\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|\psi'(x)|.$$
Also, the change of variables $x\mapsto 1-x$, and the property $\int_0^1\phi(x)\,dx=0$ gives
$$
\int_0^{1-\alpha}\psi(x)\,dx=-\int_\alpha^{1}\phi(x)\,dx=\int_0^\alpha\phi(x)\,dx.
$$
Thus,
$$\left|\int_0^{\alpha}\phi(x)dx\right| =\left|\int_0^{1-\alpha}\psi(x)dx\right| \leq \frac{1}{8}\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|\psi'(x)|= \frac{1}{8}\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|\phi'(x)|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider an $\alpha$ that is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$. Then you know that $1-\alpha \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and then we can make the substitution they give you to "pretend" we have the kind of $\alpha$ that we want (Less than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: That's not really an answer, it's just an idea that may or may not work if you work out the details.  Probably better to have posted this as a comment.

Comment: This is exactly the answer. I don't understand what you mean, this is precisely why in this particular problem you can assume that $\alpha$ is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$, because even if it is not you can transform it to be.

Comment: You may be able to fill in the omitted details in your head but I don't think most people can.

Comment: The question asked by mindy was why does the WLOG argument work in this case. To show why we can assume that $\alpha \leq \frac{1}{2}$, consider an arbitrary $\alpha$ from the interval $(0,1)$. There are two cases: $\alpha \leq \frac{1}{2}$ or $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$. In the first case, there is nothing to show. In the second case, $1-\alpha \leq \frac{1}{2}$ so we can assume that $\alpha \leq \frac{1}{2}$ after making the substitution $x\rightarrow(1-x)$

Comment: You still have to reduce the result for $\alpha>1/2$ to the case $\alpha<1/2$.  I don't know why you think that's obvious, but I really don't think it is.  If it so obvious then you can easily write down the missing details.  You have to relate $\frac18\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|f'(1-x)|$ to $\frac18\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|f'(x)|$ somehow.

Comment: It's just a misunderstanding of what was being asked. I thought Mindy was specifically asking why you can assume WLOG $\alpha \leq \frac{1}{2}$, not for the whole proof. The remaining steps are pretty trivial anyways, it's literally one substitution.

Comment: I think the argument that you can assume WLOG requires the whole proof.  Not just one step of the proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24085/discussion-between-tony-s-f-and-gregory-grant).